# springcloud-zuul mutil routes to one server in yml config

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

today,i think about one question that is how to configure mutli zuul.routes to one server without ‘**’ in yml config.

so i try to do.

there is two format in yml config：

1.like object

```
zuul:
  routes:
    every name: 
      path: path
      serviceId: server-name
```

2.key-value

```
zuul:
  routes:
    server-name: path
```

the first is succed ,but the secound is failed.

i try the second format.

**Excample:**

the /first is covered by /second ，

i find zuul.routes is Map  in ZuulProperties,

```
/**
 * Map of route names to properties.
 */
private Map<String, ZuulRoute> routes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

so the cover should be map.put().

```
zuul:
  routes:
    eureka-client-demo-01: /first
    eureka-client-demo-01: /second
```

So ,i want to know how to configure mutli zuul.routes to one server without '**' in yml config and use the second format

Comment: Is it possible that both routes would match the request and therefore first one 'wins'? Show the exact configuration anonymising the hosts and ports.

Comment: sorry.i can't understand.can u describe it in detail?

Comment: just add the exact paths you want routing from and their destinations as they appear in your actual config anonymising hosts/IPs

Comment: emm....
but what i want is filter path